# writing beautiful soup output to CSV

Tags: python

I want to write prices and corresponding addresses to a CSV file in Excel. I have this code so far which gives the output shown below in the photo.

What I want is a column for price first and a column for the address second.

```
[![from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import csv


number = "1"
url = "http://www.trademe.co.nz/browse/categoryattributesearchresults.aspx?cid=5748&search=1&v=list&134=1&nofilters=1&originalsidebar=1&key=1654466070&page=" + number + "&sort_order=prop_default&rptpath=350-5748-3399-"
r= requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)


output_file= open("output.csv","w")

price = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"property-card-price-container"})

address = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"property-card-subtitle"})


n = 1
while n != 150:
    b = (price\[n\].text)
    b = str(b)
    n = n + 1
    output_file.write(b)

output_file.close()][1]][1]
```

[image: l]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import csv
....
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
price = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"property-card-price-container"})
address = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"property-card-subtitle"})

dataset = [(x.text, y.text) for x,y in zip(price, address)]

with open("output.csv", "w", newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for data in dataset[:150]: #truncate to 150 rows
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code.  Getting the prices and addresses into separate lists risks the site switching the order of the items, etc. and getting them mixed up.  When scraping entries like this it is important to first find the larger enclosing container, then narrow down from there.

Unfortunately the URL you provided is no longer valid.  As such I just browsed to another set of listings for this example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = 'http://www.trademe.co.nz/property/residential-property-for-sale'
url += '/waikato/view-list'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:

    propertyWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for listing in soup.find_all('div',
                                 {'class': 'property-list-view-card'}):
        price = listing.find_all('div',
                                 {'class': 'property-card-price-container'})
        address = listing.find_all('div',
                                   {'class': 'property-card-subtitle'})

        propertyWriter.writerow([price[0].text.strip(),
                                 address[0].text.strip()])
```