# Scraping a table with Selenium and printing it

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, pycharm

I want to scrape all tables from a site. The automation is required to reach the tables, so you might consider that. My attempt with research is the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = Firefox(executable_path='/Users/.../PycharmProjects/Sportwinner/geckodriver')
driver.get("https://bskv.sportwinner.de/")
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id-button-einstellungen")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "id-button-einstellungen").click()
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "id-klub-name").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "id-klub-name").send_keys("Dreieck Schweinfurt")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "id-button-einstellungen-option-ok").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "id-dropdown-liga").click()
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Letzte Spielwoche").click()

tableContent = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("id-table-spiel tr")
for row in tableContent:
    print(row.text)
```

Since I just heard about Selenium a couple of hours ago, I am a total noobie. I have no clue if this works, because I don't see any output. Is anybody able to help me with my attempt (I guess it's not correct) and how it is possible for me to see the result? I am using PyCharm for compiling.

Comment: How do I reach to table ?

Comment: The automation is given in my post. But you can manually visit https://bskv.sportwinner.de and choose "Letzte Spielwoche" in the drop down menu "Eine Liga auswählen" to see the tables (my automation is more specific but I think all tables are the same)

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution was so fast that it was not able to extract details from the table.

You need apply `Implicit wait` or `Explicit waits` so that the table data shows up and can be able to extract details.

```
# Imports Required
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

...
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe") # Have tried in Chrome
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

# Or apply Explicit wait like below.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//table[@id='id-table-spiel']//tbody/tr")))

tableContent = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='id-table-spiel']//tbody/tr//div")
for row in tableContent:
    print(row.get_attribute("innerText")) # row.text works too.
```

You can try like this:

```
tableContent = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='id-table-spiel']//tbody/tr//a")

for i in range(len(tableContent)):
    tableContent[i].click() # Clicks on the "+" icon
    innerrows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='detail-view'][{}]//tr".format(i+1)) #Find the rows inside the 1st and 2nd row.
    for inrow in innerrows:
        elemnets = inrow.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div") # Data are in "div" tags
        data = [] #Collect each row in a list
        for j in elemnets:
            data.append(j.text)
        print(data)
```

```
['', '', '1', '', '2', '', '3', '', '4', '', 'Kegel', '', 'SP', '', 'MP', '', '', '', 'MP', '', 'SP', '', 'Kegel', '', '4', '', '3', '', '2', '', '1', '', '', '']
['Krug, Tobias', '141', '141', '136', '86', '141', '152', '124', '131', 'Brandl, Gerald']
['Keller, Ralf', '148', '135', '139', '130', '140', '111', '154', '145', 'Haschke, Jens']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought "time.sleep(1)" would solve this but as I said, I'm a beginner. Problem with your solution is, I need the expanded table content and not just the inner Text(?). Do you know how that would be done?

Comment: @vinceling -  Updated the answer for the same.

Comment: Did it work for you by any chance? The output is the same as before for me. The automation on clicking the + doesn't seem to work I guess - at least the table is not expanding

Comment: @vinceling - No, the code clicked on "+" and extracted all the details. See above sample output.

Comment: Yeah that was my bad, I replaced the former tableContent part instead of adding the new one afterwards. Thanks my dude, you helped me a lot!

Comment: I have a further question. Is there any possibility to redirect the output of your code to a file such as csv? @pmadhu

Comment: @vinceling -  Yes we can, and this has already been addressed. [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36755214/16452840), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46026399/16452840), [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50778481/16452840)

Comment: Yeah, I already did some research on this topic. My problem with this is that "data" is only visible in the print(data) line(?). Respectively, after the for loop data is empty with [] if I redirect the output to a file.

Comment: @vinceling - That's because `data` list is being created within the `for` loop. Create a list outside the loop and append `data` (It will become list of list) to that. Then when you print that list, you will have the list of data.

Answer (score 1):

Once you reach to the desired page, by doing `Letzte Spielwoche" in the drop down menu "Eine Liga auswählen" to see the tables`

You can use this **code** :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "id-table-spiel")))
size_of_table = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='id-table-spiel']//descendant::tr")
j = 1
for i in range(len(size_of_table)):
    element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f"(//table[@id='id-table-spiel']//descendant::tr)[{j}]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
    print(element.get_attribute('innerText'))
    j = j + 1
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but for me it's not working so far. The error states: driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)